# Hibernate: UserType - nullSafeSet - column length

Tags: hibernate, usertype

I'm defining my own UserType called FixedString and in nullSafeSet method I'd like to fill (rightPad) all strings with blanks (up to length of that column defined with annotation:

@Column(length=100, nullable=true)).

I have no problem to trim all strings in nullSafeGet method (with StringUtils.trim method):

```
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet inResultSet, String[] names, Object o) throws SQLException {
  String val = (String)Hibernate.STRING.nullSafeGet(inResultSet, names[0]);   
  return StringUtils.trim(val);
}
```

but I have no idea how I can get the length of current column (in my case COLUMN_LENGTH), so I can fill that string up with blanks (up to predefined column length)

```
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement inPreparedStatement, Object o, int i) throws SQLException {
   String val = (String)o;
   inPreparedStatement.setString(i, StringUtils.rightPad(val, COLUMN_LENGTH)));
}
```

Could anyone help me with that pls?
I'm open to any ideas...

Thanks a lot,

Rob

Answer (score 2):

Using [`inPreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData().getPrecision(i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ParameterMetaData.html#getPrecision%28int%29) as column length, will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

the usertype has a property sqltype which returns a sql string type with specified length. AFAIK  `@Column(length=100` is ignored for non string types including usertypes

Comment: So,... Does it mean, that I cannot get the length of specific column (e.g.: phone) in UserType (called FixedString in my case)?                                                                   @Column(length=100, nullable=true)
     @Type(type="com.persistence.FixedString")
     private String phone;

Comment: the usertype has to specify the column type and length. therefor the annotation is irrelevant

Comment: THX Firo. Finally I've decided to set length of Column as parameter for UserType, so I can dynamically cut strings according to individuall lengths of Columns + I keep @Column(length = 100) for proper column length by generation of DB (from HN).